# Close button to the Facebox jquery box

Tags: jquery, button, input, facebox

How can I have a close button in the popup that `Facebox` creates?

Thanks.

Comment: Facebook can create many popups. Which one are you talking about, and what does jQuery have to do with it?

Comment: Sorry I think you misread, it's Facebox.

Comment: Ah! My mistake, that makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: fyi, facebox is a terrible plugin. use something else and save yourself some headaches

Comment: @mkoryak what alternatives would you suggest? I'm needing to find something else because facebox has a double post bug in it.

Comment: whats wrong with jqueryui dialog? there are a ton of other dialog plugins around too, you can even use some of the lightbox plugins. facebox is high on google because its been around for a long time. it also hasnt been updated in a long time last i checked. it has some really bad code if you look at it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you just need to tie this to the click event of your button

```
$(document).trigger('close.facebox');
```